# Back to basic from a personal protection perspective

Tags: transactions, wallet-transfer

Apologies in advance, this may have been asked before but I can't find any answers other than "tough luck". If someone has sent Ethereum to the wrong wallet, there isn't any way to get it back, no one accountable, no help basically the person has to accept the lost. Right? So why would I back a solution that can potentially lose me my hard earnt wages? At least I have some help from my bank if a mistake is made and we all know humans are very good at making mistakes.What does Ethereum offer that protects a person from such mistakes.....nothing right? I'm just asking as I have no idea and nobody seem to have any answers. Recently I sent a small amount of Ether to a new wallet, Etherscan says the transaction was a success and something about "internal" which I don't understand and it never got to my wallet. No one seems to want to help me get my crypto back. Maybe i've been conned by this company, I don't know. But hey you live and learn. So if Ethereum has no protection for people, then what is the point? Someone educate me please. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the transaction hash of the transfer? As a new technology it take some time to learn its quirks. Quite often wallets do not work well with "internal" transactions, meaning the ether is there but they are not aware of it, that also applies to some exchanges and online wallets.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the blockchain is that there is no central instance (like a bank) that can control anything on the network. Unless you have the private key for an address, you cannot send funds from an address.

[Ethereum has checksummed addresses](https://support.mycrypto.com/troubleshooting/sending/not-checksummed-shows-when-i-enter-an-address) which can protect you from mistyping an address (when you manually enter one), but this is a very basic kind of protection. In general it's recommended to do a small test transaction before sending your funds to an address, to ensure that you are able to access those funds.

It sounds like you are talking about an internal transaction, which is a transaction sent from a smart contract to an address. These transactions don't show up as regular transactions (cause technically they aren't), but on Etherscan you can still see them on the internal transactions page ([Example](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4bbeeb066ed09b7aed07bf39eee0460dfa261520#internaltx)). You can read more about internal transactions [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/general-knowledge/ethereum-blockchain/what-are-internal-transactions). There may be a chance that the funds are on your address, without you realising it, so please double check your balance on Etherscan.